# zend framework routing 1.11

Tags: url, zend-framework, routes, router

i cant seem to get my simple route to work.

I want this URL:

example.com/restaurant/1/a-restaurant-name.html

to be converted top

example.com/restaurant?id=1*name=a-restaurant-name

i have the following Route, but it doesnt work, all i get is a redirect to my 404 page.

```
$rest_friendly = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    "/restaurant/:id/:name",
        array(
            "module"        => "default",
            "controller"    => "restaurant",
            "action"        => "index"
        )
    );
```

i have this loaded in a preDispatched Frontcontroller plugin called Route.

the plugin is 100% getting loaded as a die("Loaded") will always fire.

Additionally i have no idea how to debug this.

Comment: IIRC your should be doing this in your bootstrap as opposed to as an FC Plugin responding to an event.

Comment: To answer your other question, change the `:id` in the route to `restid` and remove the `"restid" => ":id"`. Then in your controller you can access the URL value with `$this->getRequest()->getParam('restid')`

Comment: Oops - change the `:id` in the route to `:restid` is what I mean to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preDispatch()` is called after routing has finished which is why what you have doesn't work. Like prodigitalson suggested in the comment, you should add the route in your bootstrap instead.